# Как определить текущий runtime (Dalvik или ART)?

Tags: android, runtime, dalvik

`Android runtime` (`ART`) [по умолчанию](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html) на устройствах `Android 5.0` (`API 21`) и выше.

Как можно определить текущий `runtime` на устройстве (`Dalvik` или `ART`)?

Answer (score 5):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html)

> You can verify which runtime is in use by calling
>   System.getProperty("java.vm.version"). If ART is in use, the
>   property's value is "2.0.0" or higher.

Можно воспользоваться конструкцией из следующего [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19831208/5330439)

```
private boolean getIsArtInUse() {
    final String vmVersion = System.getProperty("java.vm.version");
    return vmVersion != null && vmVersion.startsWith("2");
}
```

...

```
Log.i("log", "runtime -  ART - " + getIsArtInUse());
```

На выходе

```
I/log: runtime -  ART - false     //API < 21
I/log: runtime -  ART - true      //API => 21
```